# jQuery - not unbinding events

Tags: jquery, bind

this ones a strange one. I have a plugin in which I store all the available event names in an array so when I destroy the instance I unbind all the bound events. I have picked out one event name just for an example.

```
this.destroy = function( callback ){
    //jqElm.off('hood.changed.customiser');
    events.forEach(function(eventName){
        //console.log('hood.changed.customiser|' + eventName + '|');
        jqElm.off(eventName);
    });
};
```

the above simply does not work. If I remove the first commented out direct unbind, it does work for that event!

If I uncomment out the second, I get the following list:

> hood.changed.customiser|loading.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|loaded.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|inserted.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|hood.changed.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|hoodPrimaryFabric.changed.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|hoodSecondaryFabric.changed.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|collar.changed.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|ears.changed.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|earPrimaryFabric.changed.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|earSecondaryFabric.changed.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|tusks.changed.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|tusksPrimaryFabric.changed.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|antlers.changed.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|antlersPrimaryFabric.changed.customiser|
>   hood.changed.customiser|tail.changed.customiser|

as you can see the 3rd in the list is the event name in question but it is not unbinding!

Can anyone please shine a light on this? Regards

Comment: why don't you just say `jqElm.off('.customiser');`

Comment: flippin ek... why did I not see that in the docs... shamefully, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it is not working, but looking at you log I can see that all your events have the namespace `customiser`, so just use that to unregister events instead of the array

So

```
this.destroy = function (callback) {
    jqElm.off('.customiser');
};
```